# What locks does a REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON a PostgreSQL table require?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, locking

What locks does a REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON a PostgreSQL table require?

Specifically, could it get blocked by a long running ALTER TABLE which adds a column to the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REVOKE` and `GRANT` don't take any lock on the table itself, but they modify the table's `relacl` in [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html), so they need a `NO KEY UPDATE` lock on that row.

This will conflict with all other operations that also modify the table metadata, in particular `ALTER TABLE`.